# Pair? function applying on Quote in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket, quote, sicp

In order to implement derivative of given polynomial, I need to factorize the polynomial, i.e., `(* 3 x y)` should be the product of `3` and `(* x y)`.

So I implemented a function `multiplicand` to get the second factor of a product:

```
(define (multiplicand p) 
  (let ((second-factor (cdr (cdr p))))
  (if (pair? second-factor) (cons '* second-factor)
   second-factor)))
```

and the test code is

```
(multiplicand '(* x y))
```

But the output is `'(* y)`. It seems that the condition `(pair? second-factor)` equals `#true` with `second-factor` values `'y`.

Can anybody help me with this, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bear in mind that `(cdr (cdr ...))` is returning a list (not an element!), so `pair?` will return true if the list has enough elements (three or more). Perhaps you were aiming for something like this?

```
(define (multiplicand p) 
  (if (null? (cdddr p)) ; assuming list has at least 3 elements
      p
      `(* ,(second p) (* ,(third p) ,(fourth p)))))

(multiplicand '(* x y))
 => (* x y)

(multiplicand '(* 3 x y))
 => (* 3 (* x y))
```

Answer (score 2):

Manipulating symbolic expressions is what `match` is made for:

```
(define (multiplicand p)
  (match p
     [(list '* m n) n]
     [_ (error 'multiplicand (~a "expected product, got: " p))]))
```